# How to get a tool window title bar height in WPF?

Tags: wpf, canvas, window, size, height

WPF includes the title bar height in the total window height instead of using only the client content area height.

- Is there a way to disable this behaviour?
- If not, how can I get the height of a tool window title bar?

I'm aware of the SystemParameters.CaptionHeight property and the SystemParameters.WindowCaptionHeight property but they both return the height of a regular window title bar. This is not the correct value for a tool window because the title bar is smaller for this type of window. I need something like SystemParameters.ToolWindowCaptionHeight

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could fall back to [System.Windows.Forms.SystemInformation.ToolWindowCaptionHeight](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.systeminformation.toolwindowcaptionheight.aspx). Although it is in the WinForms namespace, it is hardly a WinForms only class.

Comment: Thanks Lars, works perfect. I'd prefer to avoid adding the Windows Forms reference to my project but this will do until there is a native WPF solution.

Answer (score 5):

The size of the client area is the actual size of the window's root element :

```
public double ClientWidth
{
    get { return ((FrameworkElement)this.Content).ActualWidth; }
}

public double ClientHeight
{
    get { return ((FrameworkElement)this.Content).ActualHeight; }
}
```

Comment: This property is useless in my context because it is read only. If there is a way to set the client area size I would be able to achieve what I'm trying to do.

Comment: I also need to do all the work before the window is shown and ActualWidth / ActualHeight are not set at that time.